# How can I always get my application to respond

Tags: c#, multithreading

I did a program that is waiting in while loop until the time input of user matching the system time ... but the problem as long it's waiting in while loop until time match it gives not responding sign and that is not so "cute", and users will think that my program is stuck .. so I want my program to look normally " no rolling mouse, no not responding sign  and no pale window" i want it to run normally .. how can I do it? I used c#

```
     private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string clock;
            clock = textBox1.Text;
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("system will close in " + clock);
            if (radioButton1.Checked)
            {
                clock = clock + " AM";
            }
            if (radioButton2.Checked)
            {
                clock = clock + " PM";
            }
            while (DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm tt") != clock)
            {
                if (DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm tt") == clock)
                    break;

            }

            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("shutdown", "/s /t 0");
            this.Close();
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string clock;
            clock = textBox1.Text;
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("system will Restart in " + clock);
            if (radioButton1.Checked)
            {
                clock = clock + " AM";
            }
            if (radioButton2.Checked)
            {
                clock = clock + " PM";
            }
            while (DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm tt") != clock)
            {
                if (DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm tt") == clock)
                    break;

            }
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("shutdown", "/r /t 0");
            this.Close();
        }

        private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string clock;
            clock = textBox1.Text;
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("system will lock in " + clock);
            if (radioButton1.Checked)
            {
                clock = clock + " AM";
            }
            if (radioButton2.Checked)
            {
                clock = clock + " PM";
            }
            **while (DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm tt") != clock)
            {
                if (DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm tt") == clock)
                    break;

            }**

            LockWorkStation();
            this.Close();

        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string clock;
            clock = textBox1.Text;
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("system will logg off in " + clock);
            if (radioButton1.Checked)
            {
                clock = clock + " AM";
            }
            if (radioButton2.Checked)
            {
                clock = clock + " PM";
            }
            while (DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm tt") != clock)
            {
                if (DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm tt") == clock)
                    break;

            }

            ExitWindowsEx(0, 0);
            this.Close(); 

        }

        private void groupBox1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your program is **constantly** checking the time. This is probably causing the behavior you see. Usually, you'll check the time, then wait a little while before checking again, thus allowing the OS process scheduler to let other program threads (like the one that handles window events) run.

You probably also want to check to make sure that the current time has not *exceeded* the target time (instead of doing a strict comparison for equality).

I don't know how you're handling GUI events or other threads, so you may need to do the sleep/yield a different way.

I assume this is Java(?). Here's an example of a mod that waits "nicely." (From `button1_Click`)

```
while (DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm tt") >= clock)
{
    if (DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm tt") >= clock)
        break;
    }
    Thread.sleep(1000);
}
```

Comment: oh sorry I didn't say.. I programmed it c#.. and thank you Ill try it ^_^

Comment: great, it's better a lot now but still not responding just I wanted to say thank you very much and about >=.. it's string and it's 10 seconds so anyway I have 1 minute to change between the input and the system clock so I kept it ==

Answer (score 1):

Should be really easy. Most of the programming languages/libraries (which are u using?) have a "wait" function, a timer or sth like that.

You would not want to use a loop cycle to wait for a certain time.